# [SOLVED]Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise] while implementing the pagination using prisma

Tags: node.js, express, pagination, backend, prisma

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]
    at Route.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\malay jeena\Documents\CODE\Web development\15_Pagination\pagination_v2\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211:15)
    at app.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\malay jeena\Documents\CODE\Web development\15_Pagination\pagination_v2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:499:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\malay jeena\Documents\CODE\Web development\15_Pagination\pagination_v2\app.js:66:5)
```

I'm getting this error when implementing the pagination, searching, sorting, filtering. This error shows up the moment I save the save file.

Also, I didn't get any errors when implementing pagination, search, sort, and filter using Mongoose. Below i've dropped the github link for this mongoose paginated api. And please aslo mention what went wrong in the prisma paginated api.

https://github.com/Malay998/pagination_mongo

Given below I've pasted the entire code for anyone to know what I'm trying to do. I've also implemented all the basic stuff like creating the prisma.schema, migration, etc.
Also please if someone solves this error, also do a quick run of the project cause I feel like after that too, there is a last bit of a problem I'll get like typeError.

app.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const userController = require('./controller/userController');
const app = express();
(async () => {
  try {
    await prisma.$connect();
    console.log('Connected to the database');
    createTestData();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
  }
})();



const usersData = [
    { firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe', email: 'johndoe1@example.com', age: 25 },
    { firstname: 'Jane', lastname: 'Doe', email: 'janedoe2@example.com', age: 30 },
    { firstname: 'Alice', lastname: 'Brown', email: 'alicebrown3@example.com', age: 28 },
    { firstname: 'Bob', lastname: 'Smith', email: 'bobsmith4@example.com', age: 35 },
    { firstname: 'Charlie', lastname: 'Johnson', email: 'charliejohnson5@example.com', age: 40 },
    { firstname: 'David', lastname: 'Williams', email: 'davidwilliams6@example.com', age: 45 },
    { firstname: 'Eve', lastname: 'Jones', email: 'evejones7@example.com', age: 50 },
    { firstname: 'Frank', lastname: 'Taylor', email: 'franktaylor8@example.com', age: 55 },
    { firstname: 'Grace', lastname: 'Lee', email: 'gracelee9@example.com', age: 60 },
    { firstname: 'Hank', lastname: 'Harris', email: 'hankharris10@example.com', age: 65 },
    { firstname: 'Irene', lastname: 'Clark', email: 'ireneclark11@example.com', age: 70 },
    { firstname: 'Jack', lastname: 'Lewis', email: 'jacklewis12@example.com', age: 75 },
    { firstname: 'Kate', lastname: 'Young', email: 'kateyoung13@example.com', age: 80 },
    { firstname: 'Larry', lastname: 'Hall', email: 'larryhall14@example.com', age: 85 },
    { firstname: 'Mary', lastname: 'Allen', email: 'maryallen15@example.com', age: 90 }
];


const createTestData = async () => {
  try {
    const userCount = await prisma.user.count();

    if (userCount === 0) {
      await prisma.user.createMany({
        data: usersData.map(user => ({
          firstName: user.firstname,
          lastName: user.lastname,
          email: user.email,
          age: user.age,
        })),
      });
      console.log('Test data created successfully');
    } else {
      console.log('Test data already exists');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating test data:', error);
  }
};

app.get('/users', userController.getUsers, userController.getAllUsers);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

pagination.js file:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();

async function getUsersWithPagination(modelName) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page) || 1;
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 5;
    const search = req.query.search || "";
    const sortBy = req.query.sortBy || 'firstname';
    const sortOrder = parseInt(req.query.sortOrder) || 1;
    const filterBy = req.query.filterBy ? req.query.filterBy.split(',') : [];
    const filterValue = req.query.filterValue || '';

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const results = {};

    if (endIndex < await modelName.count()) {
      results.next = {
        page: page + 1,
        limit: limit
      };
    }

    if (startIndex > 0) {
      results.previous = {
        page: page - 1,
        limit: limit
      };
    }

    // Add search functionality
    const searchQuery = {
      OR: [
        { firstname: { contains: search, mode: 'insensitive' } },
        { lastname: { contains: search, mode: 'insensitive' } }
      ]
    };

    // Add filtering functionality
    const filter = {};
    if (filterBy.length > 1 && filterValue) {
      const filterConditions = filterBy.map(field => {
        return { [field]: { contains: filterValue, mode: 'insensitive' } };
      });
      filter.OR = filterConditions;
    } else if (filterBy && filterValue) {
      filter[filterBy] = isNaN(Number(filterValue)) ? filterValue : Number(filterValue);
    }

    // Add sorting functionality
    const orderBy = {
      [sortBy]: sortOrder === 1 ? 'asc' : 'desc'
    };

    try {
      results.results = await modelName.findMany({
        where: { ...searchQuery, ...filter },
        orderBy,
        take: limit,
        skip: startIndex
      });
      console.log(results);
      res.paginatedResults = results;
      res.next = results.next;
      res.previous = results.previous;
      res.users = results.results.length;
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  };
}

module.exports = getUsersWithPagination;
```

userController.js:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const getUsersWithPagination = require('../util/pagination');

const getUsers = getUsersWithPagination(prisma.user);

const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = res.paginatedResults.results || [];
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      results: res.users,
      next: res.next,
      previous: res.previous,
      data: {
        users
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'fail',
      message: error
    });
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getAllUsers,
  getUsers
};
```

Comment: `getUsersWithPagination` shouldn't be `async`.

Comment: Thanks, @tkausl. You really saved my whole day. I really appreciate that. By the way, what's the point of removing the async keyword according to the error?

Comment: `async` functions return Promises.

Comment: yeah, got this. Again thanks, man.